# How to get summary output with tslm

Tags: r, lm

Here is my model:

```
mymodel <- tslm(activations ~  season + I((sold)) + I((sold1)) + I((sold2)) + trend, data =           
my_df_ts_all)
```

I can see all the coefficients fine.

But when I run summary(mymodel) I get the following error and not sure why:

> Error in quantile.default(resid) :
>
> missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

here is the code and the error:

[image]

Comment: Best guess is that `tslm` does not support missing values in your data. Remove rows with missing values before fitting the model. If you need more help, please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: `summary()` works on `tslm`, you got an error in your database. You got missing values or not supported values

Comment: Hi @Axeman. You were right! I had missing values in my data set. I am unable to mark this question answered or give you credit, however. Not sure why I am not given that option...